google recaptcha v2 invisible Php form
below is the form I am using. This form works very successfully, but there are cases where multiple forms appear on the same page. For example, on the homepage, there is only a newsletter form, but on the contact page, there is also a contact form. At this point, the two forms interfere with each other, and a form error occurs.
<form id="form2" action="<?php echo $website_url; ?>/post" method="post" class="newsletter-form" data-xhr="true">
    <input type="email" class="input-newsletter" placeholder="E-posta Adresiniz" name="email" required autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="ip_number" value="<?= $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] ?>" class="form-control input-field" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="bulten">
    <button class="btn btn-primary g-recaptcha" 
        data-sitekey="6LcFLCwqAAAAANEYbK6QZtaDav_IYRy2NUDkz4bK" 
        data-callback="onSubmit" 
        data-action="submit" 
        type="submit" id="submit">Takipte Kal</button>
</form>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.min.css"> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('submit', {
      'sitekey': '6LcFLCwqAAAAANEYbK6QZtaDav_IYRy2NUDkz4bK',
            'callback' : onSubmit
          });
  };
  

  
 $(document).on('submit', 'form[data-xhr]', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var action    = $(this).attr('action');
  var method    = $(this).attr('method');
  var formData  = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  
  

  $.ajax({

    url:  action,
    type: method,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache:false,
    data: formData,
    success:function(data) 
    {
    console.log(data);
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    swal(response.baslik, response.message, response.status).then(function () {
    grecaptcha.reset();
    if (response.status === 'success') {
    $(event.target)[0].reset();
    }
    });
    }
  });
  return false;
});
</script>

How can I overcome this situation? How can I make the form operate according to its ID? I haven't fully resolved this issue, so I would appreciate your help.
How can I overcome this situation? How can I make the form operate according to its ID? I haven't fully resolved this issue, so I would appreciate your help.
